# Ip Address and network

Tags: networking, ip

What is the exact difference between Local IP, External Ip, Static IP, Dynamic IP?
And what does it mean you should be connected on the same local network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Local v External](https://www.h3xed.com/web-and-internet/whats-the-difference-between-external-and-local-ip-addresses)

[static v dynamic](https://support.google.com/fiber/answer/3547208?hl=en)

Every IP address has a network and host part, determined by the subnet mask.
A device has an **IP** and *subnet mask* of:
**192.168.0.5**;*255.255.255.0* means that it has an network address of 192.168.0 and the rest of the ip address is allocated to hosts on the network (for a host to be on the same network it would need an ip in the range of 192.168.0.1 -> 192.168.0.254; 192.168.0.0 is the subnet address and 192.168.0.255 is the broadcast address)

another example:

A device has an **IP** and *subnet mask* of:
**192.168.0.5**;*255.0.0.0* means that it has an network address of 192 and the rest of the ip address is allocated to hosts on the network (for a host to be on the same network it would need an ip in the range of 192.0.0.1 -> 192.255.255.254; 192.0.0.0 is the subnet address and 192.255.255.255 is the broadcast address)

As a final, more complicated example, A device has an **IP** and *subnet mask* of:
**192.168.200.5**;*255.255.240.0*. To find the network we convert the mask to binary

*255.255.240.0*

*11111111.11111111.11110000.00000000*

then convert the ip to binary, and apply the mask to find our ip range of the network

**192.168.200.5**

**11000000.10101000.11001000.00000101** apply mask ->

*11111111.11111111.11110000.00000000* logical AND to get our network portion:

11000000.10101000.11000000.00000000 (192.168.192.0)

to get our first and last host address on the same network, fill in the network portion plus all 0's for the first, and all 1's for the last address:

11000000.10101000.11000000.00000000(192.168.192.0 -> subnet)

11000000.10101000.11001111.11111111(192.168.207.255-> broadcast)

so to be on the same network as **192.168.200.5**;*255.255.240.0*; a device would need an ip in the range of **192.168.192.1**;*255.255.240.0* -> **192.168.240.254**;*255.255.240.0*